# Prolog find flights

Tags: prolog

I'm having some issues with the `findall/3` in Prolog.

**Facts:**

```
% 
country(dublin,ireland).
country(cork,ireland).
country(london,uk).
country(rome,italy).
country(moscow,russia).
country(hongkong,china).
country(amsterdam,holland).
country(berlin,germany).
country(paris,france).
country(newyork,usa).
country(chicago,usa). 
country(sao_paulo,brazil).
country(rio,brazil).
```

I need to write predicate to show the connections from city `X` to city `Y` (one by one). `X` and `Y` are the two inputs (city) and `T` is the output. Each solution T is a list of all the cities connecting `X` to `Y` (`X` and `Y` included).

Example:

```
| ?- trip(rome,dublin,T).
T=[rome,london,dublin] ; 

//first solution T=[rome,paris,dublin]; 
//second solution
```

my try is

```
path(X,Y,[X|Y]):- edge(X,Y).
path(X,Y,[]):- edge(X,Z),not(member(Z,V)),path(Z,Y,[Z|V]).
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: You should put your facts one per line. It will be a whole lot easier to read. Are you studying from a Prolog book, or have you been through any tutorials?

Comment: I have put facts one per line now, yes I am reading books and looking at tutorials, however still cant get a result.

Comment: Also please explain how `country/2` comes into play.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense: first you look for `trip/3`, but trip is not defined. Later you define a `path/3` predicate based on `edge/2`, but again `edge/2` is undefined.

Comment: @repeat: in the list of `flight/6` predicates, the first one seems to be the *header*.

Comment: Try to find a better name than `country/2`, so someone can easily guess the meaning of the relation without looking at the concrete facts and / or some documentation!

Comment: @CommuSoft. OK. The question has been edited in the meantime..

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is: "how can I display all possible trip between two country ?". If so I advice you to do something like that:

```
trip(X,Y,T) :- X \= Y,
           path(X, Y, [X], T).

path(Departure, Arrival, Visited,  go(Departure, Arrival)) :- direct(Departure, Arrival) , !.

path(Departure, Arrival, Visited, go(Departure, Intermediate, GO)) :-  
                                 direct(Departure, Intermediate),
                                 Intermediate \= Departure,
                                 \+ member(Intermediate,Visited),
                                 path(Intermediate, Arrival, [Intermediate|Visited], GO).

So I also advice you to modify the facts in your knowledge base like:
    direct(rome, moskow).
    direct(moskow, paris).
    direct(paris, chicago).
    direct(sau_paolo, rio).
    direct(rio, honkong).
and so on.
```

What you did is logically uncorrect. How can you know if you can travel from a city to another only knowing where they are? There should be some facts that state that is possible travel from a city to another, e.g. direct(rome, milan) (or travel(rome, milan), you choose the functor). 
I hope to have help you.
If you have some dubt, just ask ;)

Answer (score 0):

by use prolog
Timetable of air routes
**Each air route can be described by a structure:**

country of departure, country of landing, date of departure, time of departure, duration, tariffs.

**Tariff can described by a structure:**

price for business class, price for economy class.

**Implement the following rules:**
•   Find all routes from the given country
•   Find all routes to the given country with duration less then than the given number
•   Find all routes with the cheapest price for economy class
•   Find all prices for flying from one given country to another given country

Comment: pls need for help